# css-loader URL root not modifying url

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have my `webpack.config` like so:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, root: 'http://localhost:9000/' } }
            }),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
},
```

Reading the [css-loader options documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#options) it says:

> If a root query parameter is set, however, it will be prepended to the URL and then translated.

If my css looks like so:

```
select-page {
    background-image: url('assets/background.png') !important;
}
```

I expect the output `url` to be `'http://localhost/9000/assets/background.png'`.

However, that isn't what I'm getting, there is no change when I run the build.

Answer (score 3):

So in order to get this to work, I need to make sure that I set `{ url: true }` or just leave out that key because it defaults to true.

But then because I pull my assets in via the `file-loader` I set in the css the relative url for the assets ***after*** they're moved:

```
.select-page {
    background-image: url('/assets/background.png') !important;
}
```

This poses a new problem, with `{ url: true }` this means `css-loader` is going to try and resolve it - but it can't because the files don't exist there.....

So I also have to use `{ alias: { } }` like a so:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: { 
            loader: 'css-loader', 
            options: { 
                root: 'http://localhost:8080/',
                alias: {
                    './assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/images')
                }
            } 
        }
    }),
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

This means when `css-loader` tries to resolve the `url` it will swap out `/assets` with `path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/images')` which is actually where the resources are located. But it won't affect the original `url`.

There is a reason why the key in the `alias` is prepended with a `./` because it didn't work with just a `/` and I think that is because the `css-loader` will always preprend a `/` with a `.` before it continues processing the `url`.

Then the `{ root: '' }` gets prepended to it so I get my desired output of:

```
.select-page {
    background-image:url("http://localhost:8080/assets/background.png")
}
```

This doesn't seem ideal to me - maybe it is just because my workflow is slightly different!

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the webpack configuration file. And check that assets folder should present under **src** folder

```
select-page {
    background-image: url('assets/background.png') !important;
}

module: {
    rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
            },
           {
             test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
             use: [
                 {
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]',
                 }
             ]
           }
        ]
},
```